# Rebind normal mode controls vi zsh

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh, vi

I rebind the `hjkl` movement scheme to `jkl;` in vim / evil mode and want to figure out how to do this in zsh as well. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
bindkey '\ej' backward-char
bindkey '\e;' forward-char
bindkey '\ek' down-history
bindkey '\el' up-history
```

Does anyone know the command names to do this and how to use normal mode binds?

In addition, how do I bind `h` to what is normally `;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the following:

```
# Add bindings to the vicmd keymap
bindkey -a j backward-char
bindkey -a ';' forward-char
bindkey -a k down-history
bindkey -a l up-history
```

I'm not entirely sure how to *copy* a key binding, but since `;` is bound to `vi-repeat-find` by default, you can add

```
bindkey -a h vi-repeat-find
```

Comment: This seems like it should work but it dies that `vi-forward-char` doesn't exist then lists it in the keymaps as `l`. wtf

Comment: I got lazy and unquoted *all* your key arguments since the `\e` wasn't needed. The semicolon, however, needs to be quoted because otherwise it terminates the `bindkey` command. `bindkey -a ';' forward-char`.

Comment: Oh yea fail. I've even done a fair bit of bash scripting!